# Finding regex between two - characters

Tags: regex

Can someone help me extract the name out of this string.

status-task-testing-new-connector-0

I am trying to end up with testing-new-connector

I can get it to extract up to the end of connector so it ends up status-task-testing-new-connector using regex `(?:[^-]*\-){4}([^-]*)`

but I can't figure out how to move the selector forward as far as testing.

Comment: Do you need everything in between the second and the last `-`?

Comment: Can you add more examples so that we know what can vary in your inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te pattern `(?:[^-]-){4}([^-])` repeats the non capturing group 4 times and uses a capturing group for a single time matching not a `-`

As you are using a quantifier, you could also use a quantifier in the capturing group.

If there should be at least 1 char between, you could use `+` as a quantifier instead of `*` to prevent `--` in the string.

```
^(?:[^-]+-){2}((?:[^-]+-){2}[^-]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lLrWcN/1)

Comment: Thank you that was exactly what i was looking for.